# Problem with file picker it is not working in android 13

Tags: flutter, dart, filepicker

in android 12 11 file picker is working fine but in android 13 even when permission is given file picker throws an error saying permission denied. This is my androidmanifest.xml file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:maxSdkVersion="32"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:maxSdkVersion="29"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FULL_SCREEN_INTENT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_AUDIO" />
```

This is my file picker code

```
  void pickAttachments() async {
    List<File> oldFiles = compressedFiles.isEmpty ? [] : compressedFiles;
    try {
      FilePickerResult? result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
          allowMultiple: true,
          allowCompression: true,
          type: FileType.custom,
          dialogTitle: "Pick files",
          allowedExtensions: [
            'jpg',
            'jpeg',
            'pdf',
            'webp',
            'mp4',
            'mp3',
            'rar',
            'txt'
          ]);
      if (result != null) {
        List<File> data =
            result.paths.map((path) => File(path ?? "")).toList(growable: true);
        data.addAll(oldFiles);
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          if (checkFileTypeUrl(data[i].path) == "jpg") {
            File compressedFile = await attachmentCompressor(
                data[i], data[i].path.split('/').last);
            compressedFiles.add(compressedFile);
            debugPrint(
                "File size ${getFileSizeString(bytes: compressedFile.lengthSync())}");
            debugPrint("compressed and add");
          } else {
            compressedFiles.add(data[i]);
          }
        }
      } else {
        debugPrint("No files selected !");
      }
    } catch (e) {
      debugPrint("Error occurred ${e.toString()}");
    }
  }
```

I am really stuck at here and dont know what wrong and what can i do even asking for permission is not working need so guidence thanks.

Comment: Can you share the code in which you are asking for the storage permissions ?

Comment: Could you provide the screenshot from that error message.

Comment: ok i will send screenshot from that error

Comment: Anything new on that?

Comment: well still the same in one plus but works fine on other dont know the problem yet

Answer (score 0):

Android 13 file write/read permissions for files is only available for
Media -> Images, Videos, Audios: [explanation here](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/13/behavior-changes-13#granular-media-permissions).

We have to evade this problem somehow if we want to pick other file types. So what we can do is to get information and content of picked files and copy them in our own application directory.
I had the same problem and wrote a solution in C#.

We need to create a custom file picker activity and start that activity.

In a different class, call your custom activity, in this case "FilerPickerAvtivity)

```
  var pickerIntent = new Intent(_context, typeof(FilePickerActivity));
            pickerIntent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);

            _context.StartActivity(pickerIntent);
```

In the file picker activity we open the phones files and pick any file.

```
   protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        context = Application.Context;


        var intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionGetContent);
        intent.SetType("application/pdf");


        StartActivityForResult(Intent.CreateChooser(intent, "Select file"), 0);
    }
```

Than, after picked, we try to get our data -> filename from uri and make a stream of the uri

```
  protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, [GeneratedEnum] Result resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        var uri = data.Data;

        var filename = GetFileName(context, uri);

        using var stream = ContentResolver?.OpenInputStream(uri);

        OnFilePicked(new FilePickerEventArgs(filename,stream));
         
           
        Finish();
    }

    private string GetFileName(Context ctx, Uri uri)
    {

        string[] projection = { MediaStore.MediaColumns.DisplayName };

        var cr = ctx.ContentResolver;
        var name = "";
        var metaCursor = cr.Query(uri, projection, null, null, null);

        if (metaCursor != null)
        {
            try
            {
                if (metaCursor.MoveToFirst())
                {
                    name = metaCursor.GetString(0);
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                metaCursor.Close();
            }
        }
        return name;
    }
```

You can set stream through handler and event args to other class and store the file

```
  Handler = (s, e) =>
        {
            var tcs = Interlocked.Exchange(ref _completionSource, null);
            using var stream = new MemoryStream();
            var path = StoreFileTemporaryAsync(e.Stream, e.FileName);
            FilePickerActivity.FilePicked -= Handler;
            tcs?.SetResult(path);
        };
```

Sample code:
[Github C# sample](https://github.com/Zeljko-Predjeskovic/DocumentConverter/pull/26)

Now that your File is safed in your app directory, you can do everything with it.